# Jquery Image transform not working as expected?

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick, rotation

I try to use transform image (arrow up and down) with jQuery.

It turn upside down but not back when I click again.

HTML

```
<div class="question">          
      <h3>Headline</h3>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
  <span></span>
      </div>
```

JS

```
$('.question').click(function () {
        $(this).find('span').css("transform", "rotateX(180deg)");
    });
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cuyosm41/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding the property over and over so it's not going to work. Instead, you could check if the property exists and add or remove it.

For example:

```
$('.question').click(function() {
   var arrow = $(this).find('span');

   if (arrow.css("transform") == "none") {
     arrow.css("transform", "rotateX(180deg)");
   } else {
     arrow.css("transform", "none");
   }

 });
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mikehomme/cuyosm41/1/)